exception message System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement, Version=0.7.0.0
I am getting error in Azure DevOps Pipeline for testing framework pipeline.

exception message System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement, Version=0.7.0.0

I have checked and found related to dotnet projects to give references on csproj or web config file. But In my project we won't be having any of those files
I tried online and found related to Dotnet project but not anything with out csproj file or web config file, Specific to my requirement like testing framework

Why the assembly name is wrong is hard to guess, typo perhaps.  Find it here.  Do heed the warning.

Does the same issue occur when you build and run the C# project in in Visual Studio on your local develop machine? Did you try reinstalling the required NuGet packages and dependences for your project? Try the steps in my answer below to see if the issue can be fixed. @user26558402

Have you checked with the steps mentioned below? Do they work for you? @user26558402

Try with the following steps to fix the issue:

Open the solution of your C# project in Visual Studio on your local develop machine.

Open the NuGet packages management for the project in Visual Studio. Check if there are any installed NuGet packages have the dependence "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement".

Try to reinstall the required packages for the project.

Build and and run the project in Visual Studio to ensure it can work fine.

Commit and push the updates to Azure Repos.

Run the pipeline for the updates.

If your project is .NET Framework, in the pipeline, you can use the NuGetCommand@2 task to run the "nuget restore" command to restore the required NuGet packages. It also will install the dependences  required by the packages.
If If your project is .NET Core or .NET Standard, you can use the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to run the "dotnet restore" command to restore the required NuGet packages and dependences.


In addition, go to the web.config or app.config file in your project, check and remove the the assembly binding redirects. For example, remove the binding redirects like as below.
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.1" newVersion="4.1.1.1" /> 




